# Load component which is linked to a route parameter

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Do you know if it is possible de load a component that is link to a route parameter directly inside the route config.

For exemple, I have `Exicise1Component Exicise2Component Exicise3Component`...

I would like to handle the loading inside router config :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'exercises/:id',
    component: Exercise + id
  }
];
```

I would like to avoid creating a route for each Exercise component.

Do you have an idea ? Or a better way ?

Comment: Unfortunately not like this. Plus, you’d still need to import the individual components somewhere anyway. You *could* have a single route like this, and then create a component like ‘ExerciseComponent’ and in there read the id from the router and then dynamically load the actual correct component. However, that is just moving the issue to another place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution :

I create a route where I load a component loader with parameters in the url :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':type/:id',
    component: ComponentLoaderComponent
  }
];
```

Component loader:

```
import { ExerciseComponents } from './exercises/exercises.module';
import { SolutionComponents } from './solutions/solutions.module';

@Component({
    selector: 'component-loader',
    template: ``
})

export class ComponentLoaderComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
        ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
            const componentType= params['type'] === 'exercises' ? ExerciseComponents : SolutionComponents;
            const id = params['id'] - 1;
            this.renderComponent(componentType[id]);
        });
    }

    renderComponent(component: any) {
        this.viewContainerRef.clear();
        this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(component);
    }
}
```

In my module where I declare components, I export an array with the list of the components:

```
export const SolutionComponents = [
    Solution1Component
];


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
    ],
    exports: [],
    declarations: SolutionComponents,
    providers: [],
})
export class SolutionsModule { }
```

So when the route change, it will render the component according to the route parameters.